# Lightbox expose layer (the dark layer behind) not closing

Tags: jquery, lightbox

To replicate the error go here:

http://racedayworld-com.si-eioswww3.com/

And press the button at the top right for "Post Event" .. then hit the close button at the bottom of the lightbox.

The problem:

The overlay pops up fine and it has a different colour overlayed to hide the form beneath, but it only goes away when you click the actual background and not the close button...

Comment: thats a link to your localhost..

Comment: oh sorry - here's the actual link:

http://racedayworld-com.si-eioswww3.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 214 in facebox.js:

```
 $('#facebox .close').click($.facebox.close)
```

That should be

```
 $('#facebox .close').click($.facebox.close())
```

You're missing the parens for some reason. Too much Ruby maybe? ;)